# Python Pandas - Create function to use read_excel() for multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a reusable functions in python that would read two Excel files and save save to another.

My function looks like this:

```
def excel_reader(df1, file1, sheet1, df2, file2, sheet2):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet1)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet2)

def save_to_excel(df1, filename1, sheet1, df2, filename2, sheet2):
    df1.to_excel(filename1, sheet1)
    df2.to_excel(filename2, sheet2)
```

I am calling to the functions as:

```
excel_reader(df1, 'some_file1.xlsx', 'sheet_name1', 
                df2, 'some_file2.xlsx', 'sheet_name2')

save_to_excel(df1, 'some_file1.xlsx', 'sheet_name1', 
                        df2, 'some_file2.xlsx', 'sheet_name2')
```

It do not have any errors but it do not create the Excel files that should be performed by `save_to_excel` function.

It reads the function parameters until `df2` parameter and returns error for the last two.

I will be using `pd.read_excel()` quite a number of times in my code so I am trying to make it a function. I am also aware the `the read_excel()` reads the filenames as string and tried doing `somefile.xlsx' but still the same result.

The Excel files that will be read are on the same path of the python script.

Question: Any advice on how this would work? Is it advisable to make this a function or should I just use `read_excel()` repetitively?

Comment: Can you show the line where you are trying to call the function?

Comment: @splinter Hi, I updated my question. as for the first one, I really lack arguments when I called my functions. Now that I added them, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: do you want the dunction ro returhn the two Dataframes separately, or concatenate them into one big dataframe?

Comment: I would just want to return the two Dataframes separately.

Comment: I see, see answer below. I think this is what you are trying to do

Comment: @splinter Cool! That solves it. I understand it now. I tried to put everything as a parameter, could've used `return`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return call. If you just want the function to return the dataframes then

```
def excel_reader(file1, sheet1, file2, sheet2):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet1)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet2)
    return df1, df2

df1, df2 = excel_reader('some_file1.xlsx', 'sheet_name1', 'some_file2.xlsx', 'sheet_name2')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this function would improve anything...

Just imagine that you have to call `pd.read_excel()` with different parameters for different Excel files - for example:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, 'Sheet1', skiprows=1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, 'Sheet2', usecols="A,C,E:F")
```

You will loose all this flexibility using your custom function...

Comment: I understand that. But there are quite a number of times that I will only be using:¶ 

`df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet1)`
`df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet2)`

Comment: @RickyAguilar, I think you should give us a bigger picture... What are you doing with those pairs of excel files? We can give you better answers if we will know bit more...